# Tesseract gives warning message

Tags: tesseract, tess4j

I am working with tess4j (4.3.1 version) so that I can convert image files to text file for preparing index for Lucene.It does its work but at the end gives an warning

```
Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ghost4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ghost4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.lept4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>lept4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

And my java main class:

```
        File imageFile = new File("samples/eurotext.pdf");
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
       instance.setDatapath("E:\\tessdata");
        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Using following VM arguments:

```
-Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/ocr-tess4j-example}/dlls/x64
```

Contents of dlls/x64 folder:

1. gsdll64.dll
2. liblept1760.dll
3. libtesseract400.dll

How can I get rid of the warning message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language data was not correct.Downloaded whole tessdata from [https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata] . Error gone. Got the idea from here 
https://pdfc.inetsoftware.de/public/help/tesseract4/p/optical-character-recognition

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`instance.setTessVariable("debug_file", "/dev/null");`